# How to create PUT,POST & DELETE methods using django-tastypie?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am new to django-tastypi. I had successfully created the API using following link [django-tastypie example](http://blog.brabadu.com/2011/06/easy-rest-api-with-django-tastypie.html)

But I need to implement the PUT and POST method using django-tastypie. Please any one suggest me which tutorial I need to follow. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-tastypie creates support for PUT and POST-methods automatically for you! So you don't have to implement them manually.

I found this video pretty good: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zv26xHYlc8s
It is from Daniel Lindsey, the creator of tastypie.